# Generating complete Canonical URL in umbraco using HTTP_HOST

Tags: seo, content-management-system, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use Canonical url's for my web pages. what i'm doing is :
I want complete url for the page, which i'm generating via following piece of code:

```
@{
var canonicalUrl= String.Empty;

if(umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST").ToLower().StartsWith("www")) {
  canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://", umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("umbracoUrlAlias"));
} else {
  canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://www.", umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("umbracoUrlAlias"));
}
<link rel="canonical" href="@canonicalUrl" />
}
```

I'm not sure, if this is  the expected way to do. OR if there is any better way to do.

Comment: Does your preferred domain start with "www."? I.e. its `http://www.example.com` as a pose to `http://example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide on how to set up Canonical URLs using Razor on Umbraco 7.1.x.

If you DO want the "www." in the URL, use this:

```
@using umbraco
@using System
@{var canonicalUrl= String.Empty;}
@if(umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables ("HTTP_HOST").ToLower().StartsWith("www")) {
canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://",  umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), Model.Url);
} else {
canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://www.",  umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), Model.Url);
}
<link rel="canonical" href="@canonicalUrl"  />
```

If you DO NOT want the "www." in front of the URL, then use this instead:

```
@using umbraco
@using System
@* empty out the string *@
@{var canonicalUrl= String.Empty;} 
@* check if  the requested URL starts with www. *@
@if(umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST").ToLower().StartsWith("www"))  { 
@* adds http:// to the beginning *@
canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://", umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables ("HTTP_HOST"), Model.Url); 
@* strips out the www. from the URL *@
canonicalUrl = umbraco.library.Replace(canonicalUrl,  "www.", ""); 
} else {
@* if they did not use the www prefix, we still have to add http:// to the URL *@
canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://", umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), Model.Url); 
}
<!--  output the canonical URL -->
<link rel="canonical" href="@canonicalUrl"  />
```

[Source - Canonical URLs in Umbraco CMS version 7.1.x with Razor](http://uptica.com/news/2014/canonical-urls-in-umbraco-cms-version-7-1-x-with-razor)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for us previously... Looks like what you're already using.

Using Razor syntax on Umbraco (as opposed to XSLT)...

```
@using umbraco
@using System

@{ var canonicalUrl= String.Empty; }
@if(umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST").ToLower().StartsWith("www")) {
    canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://", umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), Model.Url);
} else {
canonicalUrl = string.Concat("http://www.",   umbraco.library.RequestServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), Model.Url); }
<link rel="canonical" href="@canonicalUrl" />
```

[Source](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/code-snippets/razor-snippets/canonicalurl)